# Split URL in to page and folder variables using php?

Tags: php, url, variables, split, directory

I am currently using the following code to achieve a page, section and class variable from the url.

```
$domain = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = $domain . $path;

// page + section + class
$page = basename($url);
$page = $class = str_replace('.php','',$page);
$page = str_replace('-',' ',$page);

if ($path == "/") {
    $section = $class = "home";
} else if (basename(dirname($url),"/") == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    $section = $page;
} else { 
    $section = basename(dirname($url),"/");
    $section = str_replace('-',' ',$section);
    $class =  basename(dirname($url),"/") . " " . $class;
}
```

For example if the url is `http://www.mydomain.co.uk/about/` the code will return the following variables:

```
$page = "about"
$section = "about"
$class = "about"
```

For `http://www.mydomain.co.uk/about/general-info/`

```
$page = "general info"
$section = "about"
$class = "about general-info"
```

But when I add more depth for example For `http://www.mydomain.co.uk/about/general-info/history/` to code produces:

```
$page = "history"
$section = "general info"
$class = "general-info history"
```

where ideally I need it to output the following:

```
$page = "history"
$section = "about general info"
$class = "about general-info history"
```

or breakdown the sections into as many as needed for example:

```
$section1 = "about"
$section2 = "general-info"
```

Hopefully someone can help. If anything is unclear please ask.

Comment: can you please tell me till how many levels would the url would go? like here you have provided till the 3rd level.

Comment: In most cases it will only be until the 3rd. It could go to the 4th possibly but at present 3rd

Comment: Check the first answer by ferdinand. Its the same i prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want an URI-scheme as follows?

```
http://<domain>/<section-1>/<section-2>/.../<page>/
```

Special cases:

```
(1) http://<domain>/            -- page is empty, section is "home"
(2) http://<domain>/<section>/  -- page and section are '<section>'
```

Instead of relying on `basename()`, you should split your string into an array using `explode()` or `preg_split()`.  You can use `REQUEST_URI` directly since the domain name does not give any extra information for your sections and page.

Once you have an array, you can easily `count()` the number of path components, handle special cases for empty and size-one paths, and so on.  In the following example, I use `array_pop()` to extract the last part of the path to separate the page from the sections.  Since you seem to desire space-separated strings for sections and page, I use `implode()` to join the arrays back into a string.

```
// No need for the domain stuff!
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Split at '/', could use explode() but the PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY flag is
// very handy since it handles "//" and "/" at start/end.
$tokens = preg_split('#/#', $path, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

if (count($tokens) == 0) {
    // Special case 1
    $page = "";
    $section = $class = 'home';
} elseif (count($tokens) == 1) {
    // Specical case 2
    $page = $section = $class = $tokens[0];
} else {
    // Class contains all tokens.
    $class = implode(' ', $tokens);

    // The last part is the page.
    $page = array_pop($tokens);

    // Everything else are sections.
    $sections = implode(' ', $tokens);
}

// You seem to want spaces for dashes in the section:
$section = str_replace('-', ' ', $section);
```

Comment: Works well, thank you very much. Gives me the flexibility to show and hide and select certain elements throughout the site by testing on the $page and $section. It's a php based site using perch as the cms and so doesn't control the pages. The $class just adds a simple class to body tag just incase the page needs styling slightly differently.

To test the page or section I've been using the following:

`<?php if ($section == strstr($section, 'general information')) { ?>`

It works but is this correct or the best way to go about?

Comment: To test for a section, you should probably skip the `implode()` part, keeping the section list as an array, and use `in_array("general-information", $sections)` instead.  See: http://www.php.net/in_array

Answer (score 5):

What about using more general splitting ?

```
// Url: http://www.mydomain.co.uk/about/general-info/history/
$slices = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
// $slices == ['about', 'general-info', 'history']
```

Then do your routing as you want:

```
$class = implode(' ', $slices);
$section = $slices[1];
// etc.
```

Comment: Simple is better imo.